# Characteristic subgroup of uniquely p-divisible group that is not uniquely p-divisible

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let *p* be a prime number. Call a group *G* uniquely *p*-divisible if for every *x* in *G* there is a unique *y* in *G* such that $y^p = x$.

Question:

1. Must a characteristic subgroup of a uniquely *p*-divisible group also be uniquely *p*-divisible? In symbols, if *H* is a characteristic subgroup of a uniquely *p*-divisible group *G*, must *H* also be uniquely *p*-divisible?
2. Is the statement true if we impose the additional condition that *G* is a nilpotent group? The condition of being nilpotent is often a pretty strong restriction on the existence of various kinds of roots, so I think this is much more plausible.

What I know:

A. The statement is true if the big group *G* is abelian. This is because multiplication and division by *p* become automorphisms and hence must preserve any characteristic subgroup.

B. The statement is true if *G* is finite. In fact, if *G* is finite, this is equivalent to saying that the order of *G* is relatively prime to *p*, and hence *all* subgroups are uniquely *p*-divisible.

C. For infinite groups, we can have non-characteristic subgroups that violate the condition. For instance, the group of integers in the group of rational numbers. The big group is uniquely *p*-divisible for all *p*, but the group of integers is not uniquely *p*-divisible for any *p*.

Answer (score 10):

The first example of a finitely generated divisible group was constructed by Guba in Guba, V. S. A finitely generated complete group.  Izv. Akad. Nauk SSSR Ser. Mat.  50  (1986),  no. 5, 883–924. Similarly one constructs a $p$-divisible group. Start with the free group $F=F(a,b)$, enumerate all non-identity elements of $F$: $w_0,w_1...,$. Then let $G_0=F$, and at every step $n \ge  0$, if the word $w_n$ is a $p$-th power in $G_n$, do nothing, otherwise impose one additional relation $w_n=U_n^p$, where $U_n$ is "long and complicated". The new group is $G_{n+1}$. It is easy to see that the limit group $G_\infty$ is  $p$-divisible. It is possible to prove also that it is going to be uniquely $p$-divisible, provided $U_n$ satisfy some small cancelation condition. Now, let $w_0=[a,b]$ be the commutator (it does not matter how you enumerate the words in $F$), and $U_0$ be not in the derived subgroup (the choice of $U_0$ is almost arbitrary). Then the derived subgroup of $G_\infty$ will not be $p$-divisible. The derived subgroup is of course characteristic. This answers your first question. For nilpotent groups the answer may be different indeed.

Answer (score 8):

I think the approach suggested by Mark works, but one has to be a bit more careful. The problem is that, in Mark's notation, if $U_0$ is not in the derived subgroup of $F$, it does not follow automatically that the image of $U_0$ will not be in the derived subgroup of $G_\infty $. To ensure this property one has to be more careful with the choice of other $U_i$'s.

The best illustration of this problem is the following observation: if $G$ is finitely generated and divisible, then $[G,G]=G$ and in particular $[G,G]$ is divisible. Indeed, $G/[G,G]$ is a finitely generated divisible abelian group, hence it is trivial, i.e. $[G,G]=G$. Nevertheless, this approach should work after some modifications, which are obvious to experts (e.g., to Mark).

Alternatively, one can find examples of uniquely p-divisible groups whose derived subgroups are not p-divisible in the old paper [G. Baumslag, Some aspects of groups with unique roots, Acta Math. 104 1960 217–303].  These are so-called free $D_\omega $-groups.

If I am not mistaken, in the same paper Baumslag proved that every term of the lower central series, upper central series, or derived series of a uniquely divisible nilpotent group is again (uniquely) divisible. However I do not see why it should be so for other verbal subgroups.

Comment: Thanks for the references and issues you raised! As for your example of $G^p$, if I understand your notation correctly, then G^p = G when G is uniquely p-divisible, so that couldn't generate a counterexample. You probably had something slightly different in mind.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I corrected the answer.


Answer (score 1):

The example of $GA^+(1,\mathbb{R})$ here works as a counterexample:

http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Characteristic_not_implies_powering-invariant_in_solvable_group