# When is the set of $n$-th powers in a group a subgroup?

Tags: gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a non abelian group and $G_n=\{x^n | x\in G\}$ and n is integer. Is there a sufficient condition that makes $G_n$ be a subgroup of $G$ for arbitrary $n$?

Comment: You might be interested to read the work of J.L. Alperin on n-Abelian groups..

Comment: Suppose that $G$ is a finite $p$-group. Then two such sufficient conditions are that $G$ be "regular", and that $G$ be "powerful". Wikipedia pages have good references for these concepts.

Comment: If in $G$ every element is an $n$th power then $G_n=G$. For example if every element of $G$ has order co-prime with $n$, then $G_n=G$.

Comment: Mark sapir that is obvious..I am asking for a general case..

Comment: But there are lots of sufficient conditions. You need to make it clearer what kind of condition you are looking for.

Comment: Some clickable links:  one example of @GeoffRobinson's suggestion, [Alperin - A classification of $n$-Abelian groups](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/classification-of-n-abelian-groups/7DE7A6C843AABB454A8471A3298EA6C7) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=248204)).

Comment: @RichardLyons's suggestions:  [regular $p$-group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_p-group) (and on [EoM](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Regular_p-group)); [powerful $p$-group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerful_p-group).

Comment: Derek Holt can you help me with some links or refrences for these conditions?

Answer (score 3):

One can construct examples of such groups which are not abelian via combinatorial group theory.

Clearly a group $G$ has this property for all $n$ if $\forall x, y\in G, \forall n, \exists z\in G$, $x^ny^n=z^n$.

For a group $G$, let us construct a group $G^R$ so that $G < G^R$ and for all $x,y\in G,  \forall n$, there exists $z\in G^R$ such that $x^ny^n=z^n$.

To create such a group, we simply add a new element $g_{x,y,n}$ for each such pair $(x,y)\in G\times G, n\in \mathbb{N}$, so that $(g_{x,y,n})^n=x^ny^n$. If $x^ny^n$ has infinite order in $G$, then we see that this is an amalgamated free product with $\mathbb{Z}$, hence $G$ injects into $\langle G, g_{x,y,n} | (g_{x,y,n})^n=x^ny^n \rangle$. If $x^ny^n$ has order $m$, then we also assume that $g_{x,y,n}$ has order $nm$, and hence we also get a free amalgamated product of $G$ with $\mathbb{Z}/nm\mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$. Taking a union of these amalgamated products, we see that $G$ will inject in the group $$\langle G, g_{x,y,n} | (g_{x,y,n})^n=x^ny^n, x,y\in G\times G, n\in\mathbb{N} \rangle = G^R.$$

Now, iterate, taking $G_0=G, G_{i+1}=(G_i)^R$, and $\hat{G} = \underset{i}{\cup}\ G_i$. Any $x,y\in \hat{G}$ will lie in $G_i$ for some $i$, and hence $x^ny^n=z^n$ will have a solution $z\in G_{i+1} \subset \hat{G}$.

This shows that if you allow (presumably) infinitely generated groups, your class of groups can contain any given group as a subgroup. In particular, your condition does not give a variety of groups (such as the $n$-Abelian groups), which is to be expected given the quantifier formulation.

Comment: Just to mention, existence of "many" divisible groups (e.g., algebraically closed groups) is a classical application of HNN extensions (say, this shows that every countable group embeds in a divisible countable group). More difficult, using small cancellation ideas Guba (1986) constructed finitely generated nontrivial examples, see [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/90448/14094). To make this construction different, you maybe want to obtain non-divisible groups (and avoid trivialities such as (divisible)$\times$(abelian), e.g. imposing $\bigcap_n G^n=\{1\}$).